# VHDL simulation errer (XX)

Tags: vhdl, simulation, error

I'm interested in verilog, but I have a big problem.
I'm trying to simulate my code but VHDL simulation shows 'X' for output.
[[image: a busy cat](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=vhdl%20errer)[two muppets]]

[[image: a busy cat](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=vhdl%20errer)[two muppets]] 
This is a modulo.vhd
[[image: a busy cat](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=vhdl%20errer)[two muppets]]
This is a tb_modulo-vhd
[[image: a busy cat](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=vhdl%20errer)[two muppets]]
This is a simulation.
Any suggestions on where I made the mistake?

Comment: Please post code as text as opposed to an image

Comment: That code is too long to post a comment. I think while loop is wrong. So I post while loop.                                              while (c>=d) loop
             c <= c-d;
        wait for 10 ns;
        end loop;
        remainder <= std_logic_vector (resize(signed(c), remainder'length));

Comment: You can edit your question. With the code in an image, nobody can copy your it to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The process is stalling at

```
 while (c>=d) loop
   c<=c-d;
 end loop;
```

VHDL signals are not updated until the end of a process with sensitivity or a WAIT (as nonblocking assignments in Verilog)

This is an endless loop.

You can add a "wait for 10ns" statement within the while loop.

Or you can use variables for b,c,d.

Comment: Umm... I'm sorry but how do I fix it? I added "wait for 10ns", but it doesn't work.